# "No nodes configured for partition" after creating a database via ETL

Tags: orientdb

I've just created a custom database using the following ETL config,

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "./mydata.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "row": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "csv": {} },
    { "vertex": { "class": "MyClass" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:/opt/orientdb/databases/MyData",
       "dbUser": "root",
       "dbPassword": "qrefhiuqwriouhwqv",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "MyClass", "extends": "V"},
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I go to the web console, I can see I have 433k records of type MyClass created at database MyData.

When I try to query it with "select from MyClass", I get the error

```
2015-04-06 23:56:25:541 SEVERE Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: 
No nodes configured for partition 'MyClass.[]' request: 
id=-1 from=node1428362873334 task=command_sql(select from MyClass) userName= [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OrientDB version?

Comment: I am using OrientDB 2.0.5

Comment: Seems you're running distributed. Could you try running the server with server.sh instead of dserver.sh?

Comment: I am running with "server.sh -Ddistributed=true"